# visual studio 2010 single project with multiple cpp files with main

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, program-entry-point

I want to examine a lot of little cpp files that have `int main()` , and run only one of them at one running .  something like this  -

[image]

Is there any way to do that without open new project for every cpp file  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can choose not to compile the files. Go to the properties, and exclude the file from build.

Answer (score 4):

No. In a project, you cannot have multiple `main()` function.

You can rename them to `test1()`, `test2()`, `test3()`, and call them one by one from `main()`. That is what I do usually.

Comment: but for that you'll need to create header files for each of these and include the header file of say `test1`, as `#include "test1.h"`, at the beginning of the `main.cpp` file right?